# React native custom view meet has no propType issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have customized text view in my android app. And I want to use it with react native. So I follow the guide and write it as:

```
public class CustomizedTextViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<CustomizedTextView> {
...
}
```

It works, but can't adjust textview's height based on its content. I have to give a height in render(), otherwise the textview will not be expanded.
What I want is that it can reset its height base on its content, just like what Rn textview did.

```
render(){
...
<CText style={styles.message} >{message.text}</CText> // CText is the CustomizedTextView
...
}

cosnt styles = ...({
...
message:{
        ...
        height: 100,
}
...
})
```

Problem is that it looks urgly when there was little content in the textview.
So I look into ReactTextViewManager.java and re-write my view like:

```
public class CustomizedTextViewManager extends BaseViewManager<CustomizedTextView,ReactTextShadowNode> {
...
}
```

It shows: 
CustomizedTextView has no propType for native prop CustomizedTextView.allowFontScaling of native type boolean

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Forget to say, it's react 0.49.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, my bad.

The error already hints that I should set props like 'allowFontScaling'.
At first I thought I missing implement 'allowFontScaling' in my native manager. But it shouldn't be. The native manager is already the sub-class of Rn text manager, which should implement all props.

Finally in Rn debugger I find that I should add Text.propTypes and View.proTypes in propTypes in 'CText.js'

Solution:

```
var iface = {
    name: 'GSMText',
    propTypes: {
        myProp1: PropTypes.string,
        myProp2: PropTypes.number,
        ...Text.propTypes, // must add this tow propTypes 
        ...View.propTypes, // other wise will see the red screen 
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.